# RAD Studio found some failed deferred GetIt packages

Tags: delphi, rad-studio, delphi-12-athens

Every time I open my Delphi 12, then I get a Popup info box that says the following:

> RAD Studio found some failed deferred GetIt packages. You can revise the list of packages that failed in the GetIt Packages dialog box, and decide to cancel them or try to process them again when the IDE is closed.

It opens while loading the packages before the whole IDE opens, as can be seen here:

[image: RAD Studio found some failed deferred GetIt packages Error message screenshot]

The only GetIt packages I have that are installed are FMXLinux 1.76, Bonus Radiant Shapes 1.5, and SynEdit for VCL 2023.08:

[image: Delphi GetIt screenshot]

I don't know how to get rid of this message. It appears every time.

Why am I getting it, and how can I stop it from appearing every time I open my IDE?

Comment: Sounds like something you should be asking [Embarcadero Support](https://www.embarcadero.com/support) about.

Comment: I have the same problem after install patch.R120.patch1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely uninstalling and reinstalling my whole IDE fixed the issue for me.

After I reinstalled Delphi, I was able to open Delphi without the messages appearing. Even after installing the same GetIt packages that I had before. I no longer get those messages.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I deleted the values "DeferredComponents" and "DeferredComponentsInstallFailed" from HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\23.0\CatalogRepository and that fixed it.